# Correct Syntax for Robot.txt File?

Tags: wordpress, search, robots.txt

What's below is in my Robot.txt file.

If I want a particular Search engine to have access to the site, but not a few key areas, such as the admin section, the wp-content area, and a folder that is non-existent, is the syntax that I have below correct for google, msn, bing, yahoo, duckduckbot, but to disallow everyone else ?

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: MSNBot
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: Bingbot
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: Slurp
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: DuckDuckBot
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: Googlebot-Image/1.0
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: Googlebot-Video/1.0
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Allow: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /wp-content/*
Disallow: /docs/*

User-agent: *
Disallow: *
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is correct, but approach is wrong.

**1. Never block your content**

Google (and many other search engines) fully renders your page. If you block access to images, Google drops down your position is search results, just for a case. Googlebot cannot understand if your page is full of broken links to images, or not.

This is a [quote](https://yoast.com/google-panda-robots-css-js/) from [Maile Ohye](https://www.linkedin.com/in/maileohye/), Google Developer Programs Tech Lead:

> “We recommend making sure Googlebot can access any embedded resource that meaningfully contributes to your site’s visible content or its layout”

**2. Do not block /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php**

When you block access to `/wp-admin/` entirely, no ajax content is available for robots. That is why standard robots.txt generated by WordPress on the fly is as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

**3. Do not block other bots**

List of search bots are wider than shown in your question, and grows occasionally. In your list, for example, `Googlebot-Mobile` does not present. The last statement in your file blocks access to this bot with evident results for mobile search.

It is better not to invent a bicycle, but use standard WordPress robots.txt settings shown above or even [wider settings](https://yoast.com/wordpress-robots-txt-example/) by [Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) (1+ million installs).